# Jupiter's impact on Juno's solar panels

Tags: jupiter, solar-power, juno

Juno has large solar panels on it.   I was curious about their effectiveness when Juno is closest to Jupiter.

Does Jupiter have a significant impact on the solar panels?   Can the solar panels convert Jupiter's radiation into energy?     Does Jupiter's large magnetosphere impede the solar panels ability to convert the sun's energy into power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solar panels cannot convert radiation found in the magnetic fields to energy. The radiation will degrade the solar panels over time, to the point where they eventually will not produce as much power as they do now. The panels were purposely built in such a way to accept this degradation in power over time.

Juno will no go into eclipse during it's mission lifetime, except for during the Earth flyby. There will be minimal effect overall from being close to Jupiter, aside from the long term radiation degradation.

Comment: "*The solar panels cannot convert radiation to energy.*" That's exactly what solar panels do; sunlight is a form of radiation. You might want to rephrase that first sentence.

Comment: I suppose there's truth to that statement, I've re-worded appropriately.